# Coherent waves and phase difference

Tags: optics, waves

One of the property of coherent wave is they must have a constant phase difference. Also it's said that they are in phase. So does that mean the constant phase difference is equal to zero?

Comment: No; a wave can be described as being coherent in space and in time, and these are different properties. If the constant phase difference is exactly zero, over either space or time, it would immediately have consequences for the wave.

Comment: In phase is one of an infinite number of possibilities for there to be a constant phase difference.